# $|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2| + \max(|z_1|,|z_2|) , \forall z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, complex-numbers

I tried to solve an olympiad-level problem with complex numbers by myself. Can you please look at my solution and tell me if it is correct and complete, and how many points I would have gotten out of 7? I hope I didn't miss anything.

> Prove that for any complex numbers $z_1 , z_2$ the following inequality holds $$|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2| + \max(|z_1|,|z_2|)$$

*My solution* :

First we check if one of the 2 complex numbers is $0$, we assume that it is $z_1$ $\implies |z_2|+|z_2| \le 0 + |z_2|+|z_2| \implies |z_2| \le |z_2|$and we obtain the equality in the inequality.

From now, we will assume that the two numbers are different from $0$. Let's approach the case when $z_1,z_2$ have the same modulus, so let $|z_1| = |z_2| = r , r\in \mathbb R , r>0 $, we have to prove that $|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le 3r$. We will use that $|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2 = 2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2) = 4r^2$ for the inequality $(|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2|)^2 \le 2(|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2) \implies |z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le \sqrt{8r^2} $ . So, to prove this case, it is enough to show that $2 \sqrt2 r \le 3r \iff 2 \sqrt2 \le 3 \iff 8 \le 9 $ (we used that $r$ is a strictly positive real number).

Now we can move to a more general case. We assume without losing generality that $|z_1| < |z_2|$. Let $r_1= |z_1|$ and $r_2= |z_2|$ , $r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb {R} , r_1,r_2 >0 , r_2>r_1$.Then, $\max(|z_1|,|z_2|) = |z_2|$. So we have to prove that $|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le |z_1| + 2|z_2|, \forall z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C , |z_2|>|z_1| , z_1,z_2 \ne 0$.
Similar to the previous case, we have that $|z_1+z_2|^2+|z_1-z_2|^2 = 2(|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2)=2(r_1^2+r_2^2) \implies |z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2| \le 2 \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2}$

So, to complete the problem, all we need to prove is that : $2 \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2} \le r_1 + 2r_2 , \forall r_1,r_2 \in \mathbb R , r_2 > r_1 , r_1,r_2 > 0$ $2\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2} \le r_1 + 2r_2 \iff 4r_1^2+4r_2^2 \le r_1^2+4r_2^2+4r_1r_2 \iff r_1(4r_2-3r_1) \ge 0$ which is obviously true because $r_1>0$ and $4r_2>4r_1>3r_1$.

This is my solution. How many points would I take out of 7? I am open to any suggestion, comment or even a different solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mathslover Is there something wrong with the proof there?

Comment: try to use triangle inequality for both the cases $|z_1+z_2|+|z_1-z_2|$

Comment: @zero_infinity I don't understand what it has to do with what I asked.

Comment: @zero_infinity OP is asking if the solution is right, is not asking for a simpler solution.

Comment: At first I was thinking he has asked whether his solution is right or wrong but he also asked for a different and better solution and I am quoting him:- "I am open to any suggestion, comment or even a different solution. Thank you very much!"

Answer (score 2):

I have not read your proof ... but I think one could simplify computations  by noticing that rotation or scaling (that is multiplying both numbers by the same factor) does not change the inequality. With this in mind, all we have to prove is this:
$|1 + z| + |1-z| \leq 2 +|z|$

 where
$|z| \leq 1$.

Then one just raises both sides to the second, uses some identities like 
 $|a+b|^2 + |a-b|^2 = 2|a|^2 + 2|b|^2$ and $(1-z)(1+z) = (1-z^2)$ and everything simplifies to 
 $|1-z^2| \leq 1 +|z|^2 \leq (1+|z|)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I thought similar for a moment to prove that the inequality is homogeneous, but I didn't continue with this idea. Can you also look at my solution and tell me if it is correct and how many points would I take out of 7?

Comment: Looked at your solution and it seems to be Ok. Now, to be frank, it is kind of "overtalked" one. All you really need is the last case.  If I were to grade it I would give you full score (7 out of 7) or, on a bad, day 6. But I was always considered a lenient grader. Definitely you showed some work. This has to be appreciated. But also some lack of, how to put it, mathematical maturity let's say.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!